# PubNub Windows Phone 8 (Connects only when in Debug mode)

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, pubnub

I am trying to connect to pubnub via Windows Phone 8.
But the connection only takes place when I debug the application on the device.
If the app isn't debugging it no longer connects I also don't see any errors (no MessageBox or app crashes).

```
private void PubnubCallbackResult(string result)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("RESULT CALLBACK: " + result.ToString());
    });
}

private void PubnubConnectCallbackResult(string result)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CONNECT CALLBACK: " + result.ToString());
    });
}

private void PubnubDisconnectCallbackResult(string result)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("DISCONNECT CALLBACK: :" + result.ToString());
    });
}

private void PubnubDisplayErrorMessage(PubnubClientError result)
{
    if (!hideErrorCallbackMsg)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR CALLBACK: :" + result.ToString());
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After talking to the team at PubNub there is a fix on the development branch that should be available on the master branch soon via their C# github repo (https://github.com/pubnub/c-sharp/tree/master/windows-phone-8).

Comment: Merged to master as of yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

AJ, does the sample app for WP8 work for you?  It is available here:

https://github.com/pubnub/c-sharp/tree/master/windows-phone-8

Comment: Geremy awesome link! I give you one fruit basket for this.

Comment: It is indeed an awesome link!

Comment: I'm able to publish to the channel, but subscribe doesn't give me any feedback (unless I select it twice then it informs me I'm already listening). It does work when I am debugging the app though (same as before).

Comment: I noticed the demo app works on the emulator wether I'm debugging or not.

Comment: AJ, please contact us at support@pubnub.com, and we'll get more information on your app, and try to reproduce. Once reproduced, we'll get a fix out to you ASAP.